# Compressing files from a Python Dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, python-3.7

I have created a dataframe using panda in Python. The dataframe uses two columns from a .csv file called filepath and filename, joins them and then outputs in full.

I am trying to use this output to zip the filename in question but it isn't working properly and just overwrites the file.

```
import pandas as pd
import zipfile
import os
from os import path
from os.path import basename
 
column_names = ["Path", "Filename", r"Path"]
df = pd.read_csv(r"resources.csv", usecols= ["Path","Filename"])
df = df.dropna()
df = ["/".join(i) for i in zip(df["Path"].map(str),df["Filename"].map(str))]

rows = list(df)
for row in rows:
    

    print (row)
```

I added the zipfile.ZipFile entries in the for row in rows block but replaced with print(row) to produce the list.

Can anybody help point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import zipfile
import os
from os import path
from os.path import basename


 
column_names = ["Path","Filename" r"Path"]
df = pd.read_csv(r"resources.csv", usecols= ["Path","Filename"])
df["fullpath"] = df[["Path","Filename"]].agg("/".join, axis=1)
df["zipfilename"] = df["Filename"].str.replace(r'.py', '')

rows = list(df.values)

for row in rows:
    zip = zipfile.ZipFile(row[3] + '.zip', 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
    zip.write(row[2], basename(row[1]))
    zip.close()

    print (row)
```

After some head scratching i managed to get exactly what I needed from the dataframe and zip individual files.